RegEx for checking coordinates in various formats
I would like to verify a coordiantes-entry with a RegEx that will accept coordinates in the decimal format as well as in degrees/minutes/seconds.
I came as far as you can see below. It works with the degree/minutes/seconds-input but fails to identify the latitude in the decimal format, the longitude is correct:
Input e. g.:
48.20801690888307, 16.371340225941758
N 48° 12' 28.0044" E 16° 22' 17.1588"

Pattern:
(?:([0-8]?[0-9]|90)°(\s[0-5]?[0-9]')?(\s[0-5]?[0-9](,?\.?[0-9]+)?"))|((?:\w?\s?[0-9]{1,3})(?:\.?\,?[0-9]+)\s?\w?)$

I tried to find the mistake, but stranded at this point. I would be grateful for every help.

In your regex, you are looking for the seconds symbol (") but it is not in your sample input.

Maybe this does what you want? (?:([0-8]?[0-9]|90)°(\s[0-5]?[0-9]')?(\s[0-5]?[0-9](,?\.?[0-9]+)?))|((?:\w?\s?[0-9]{1,3})(?:\.?\,?[0-9]+)\s?) example here

There are many more formats, e.g. 41°24'12.2"N 2°10'26.5"E. Do you need a generic coordinates pattern, to support NWSE on both ends? I have a regex for coordinates but only when NSWE are on the right.

Are you using it in JavaScript?

If your regex engine supports conditional constructs, I can share a pattern.

Please add a tag for the regex version or the programming language you are using.

The (")-symbol should be inclouded of course, I adapted this now. The NESW ending/prefix should be supported as well. Thanks for the comment.

I'd use a less "restricted" pattern, and would code the rest, if necessary:
\s*([NESW])\s*([0-9]+)\s*°\s*([0-9]+)\s*['\"]?\s*([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?['\"]?|\s*([0-9]+)\.([0-9]{6,})\s*

Code:
import re


def _extract(s):
    p = r"\s*([NESW])\s*([0-9]+)\s*°\s*([0-9]+)\s*['\"]?\s*([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?['\"]?|\s*([0-9]+)\.([0-9]{6,})\s*"
    f = re.findall(p, s)
    return f


s = """48.20801690888307, 16.371340225941758
N 48° 12' 28.0044" E 16° 22' 17.1588  S   48° 12' 28.0044"  W    16°   22' 17.1588"""

print(_extract(s))

Prints
[('', '', '', '', '', '48', '20801690888307'), ('', '', '', '', '', '16', '371340225941758'), ('N', '48', '12', '28', '.0044', '', ''), ('E', '16', '22', '17', '.1588', '', ''), ('S', '48', '12', '28', '.0044', '', ''), ('W', '16', '22', '17', '.1588', '', '')]

Note

There are seven groups in the pattern, you can add/remove, however you want.
The last two are for the 48.20801690888307, 16.371340225941758.
The first five are for these input types E 16° 22' 17.1588.


Thanks, this is the perfect (and more elegant) solution. I adapted it so point and comma is accepted and NESW is possible in front as well as on the end. It now looks like this:        \s*([NESW])?\s*([0-9]+)\s°\s([0-9]+)\s*['"]?\s*([0-9]+)(.?,,?[0-9]+)?['"]?\s*([NESW])?|\s*([0-9]+).?,?([0-9]{6,})\s*
